# Help! Unable to get results required

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008(R2)

I have a result set that I need displaying in a different way, it is currently available like:

```
Resource    Nr  Cost    StartDate   EndDate  
Cable_5m    8   3.5 12/03/2011  13/03/2011  
Cable_5m    2   3.5 13/03/2011  14/03/2011  
Rope125A    1   0   16/03/2011  18/03/2011  
Rope125A    1   0   17/03/2011  17/03/2011
```

What I need is to report on a date basis how many of each resource are sent, like below:

```
DateOfEvnt Resource Nr Cost  
2011-03-12 Cable_5m 8 3.50  
2011-03-13 Cable_5m 10 3.50   
2011-03-14 Cable_5m 2 3.50  
2011-03-16 Rope125A 1 0.00  
2011-03-17 Rope125A 2 0.00  
2011-03-18 Rope125A 1 0.00
```

I have looked at pivot but cannot for the life of me get it to work, and I am not sure pivot is what I need. All help would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 1):

For given in and outputs, you don't need a `PIVOT` at all. A simple `UNION` and `GROUP BY` would suffice.

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @Resources TABLE (
    Resource VARCHAR(32)
    , Nr INTEGER
    , Cost FLOAT
    , StartDate DATE
    , EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Resources 
    SELECT 'Cable_5m', 8, 3.5, '03/12/2011', '03/13/2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Cable_5m', 2, 3.5, '03/13/2011', '03/14/2011'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Rope125A', 1, 0,   '03/16/2011', '03/18/2011' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Rope125A', 1, 0,   '03/17/2011', '03/17/2011'
```

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  DateOfEvnt
        , Resource
        , Nr = SUM(Nr)
        , Cost      
FROM    (           
            SELECT  Resource
                    , Nr
                    , Cost
                    , [DateOfEvnt] = StartDate
            FROM    @Resources
            UNION ALL       
            SELECT  Resource
                    , Nr
                    , Cost
                    , [DateOfEvnt] = EndDate
            FROM    @Resources
        ) r         
GROUP BY
        Resource
        , Cost
        , DateOfEvnt
```

**EDIT**
While the `UNION` and `GROUP BY` satisfy the results, I'm starting to suspect you are more in need of something like this where the `WITH` statement returns a record for each day between `Start-` and `EndDate`.

```
;WITH q AS (
    SELECT  Resource
            , Nr
            , Cost
            , StartDate
            , DateOfEvnt = StartDate            
    FROM    @Resources
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  q.Resource
            , q.Nr
            , q.Cost
            , q.StartDate
            , DATEADD(day, 1, q.DateOfEvnt)         
    FROM    q
            INNER JOIN @Resources s ON s.Resource = q.Resource
                                       AND s.Nr = q.Nr
                                       AND s.StartDate = q.StartDate
    WHERE   q.DateOfEvnt < s.EndDate
)
SELECT  DateOfEvnt
        , Resource
        , Nr = SUM(Nr)
        , Cost
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        DateOfEvnt
        , Resource
        , Cost
```

Comment: That won't give 2xRope125A on 17th, will it?

Comment: @Damien - yes it will. Did you copy pasted the scripts and had different results?

Comment: +1 for the second version. The first version does give the correct result with this sample data but it is because Rope125A on 17th is counted twice for the third row. Once for StartDate and once for EndDate, not because of the overlap.

Comment: Thanks Lieven, however on a larger data set the fugures seem to wander some what from the truth. Try the following data set                                                                  Resource NrSent ItemCost SubEvntStart SubEvntEnd
1615 10 0.25 07/02/2011 22/03/2011
1615 4 0.25 01/03/2011 08/04/2011
1615 2 0.25 07/03/2011 01/04/2011
1615 10 0.25 14/03/2011 21/03/2011
1615 5 0.25 15/03/2011 21/03/2011
1615 5 0.25 15/03/2011 22/03/2011
1615 4 0.25 18/03/2011 19/03/2011
1615 4 0.25 18/03/2011 19/03/2011